# Having trouble with before action using the devise gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I'm still learning rails so i guarantee my problem is really simple.

My site has 3 controllers;  Scripts, Users and Pages.  My problem is if a user isn't signed in they are automatically sent straight to the login/sign up page due to my before action on my Scripts controller.  I don't want this to happen when a user is on my root page which is associated to my Pages controller?

```
  before_action :set_script, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Ive tried experimenting with but I cant seem to figure it out

```
  before_action :set_script, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [:new, :show, etc]
```

Thanks Stack overflow

Also this is my log for rails s

```
Processing by PagesController#index as HTML
Completed 401 Unauthorized in 8ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 1163)
Started GET "/users/sign_in" for 127.0.0.1 at 2020-05-06 20:34:21 +1000
Processing by Devise::SessionsController#new as HTML
  Rendering devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application
  Rendered devise/shared/_links.html.erb (Duration: 1.6ms | Allocations: 713)
  Rendered devise/sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (Duration: 11.2ms | Allocations: 3029)
[Webpacker] Everything's up-to-date. Nothing to do
  Rendered layouts/_nav.html.erb (Duration: 0.7ms | Allocations: 452)
  Rendered layouts/_messages.html.erb (Duration: 0.4ms | Allocations: 204)
  Rendered layouts/_footer.html.erb (Duration: 0.3ms | Allocations: 79)
Completed 200 OK in 104ms (Views: 86.1ms | ActiveRecord: 6.2ms | Allocations: 22723)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to omit before_action :authenticate_user! from my application controller

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    before_action :authenticate_user!
    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    end

end
```

to

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base

    before_action :configure_permitted_parameters, if: :devise_controller?
    protected

    def configure_permitted_parameters
      devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:name])
    end

end
```

Comment: There is a rails method that does exactly that: https://apidock.com/rails/v5.2.3/AbstractController/Callbacks/ClassMethods/skip_before_action. It allow you to keep the generic behavior `authenticate_user!` while only skipping it when it is not needed. In your case, in the PagesController: `skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: [...]`

Answer (score 0):

You should leave the `before_action :authenticate_user!`, to make by default all your controller actions not public

If you need in some controller to make an action public, then in the specific controller, so your `PagesController`, you can skip a `before_action` with something like

```rb
    class PagesController < ApplicationController
      skip_before_action :authenticate_user!, only: :home

      def home
      end
    end
```

This will make the `home` action public